# Print out hours and minutes with date?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DATE(P_DAYS IN  NUMBER) RETURN DATE AS V_DATE DATE;
BEGIN
V_DATE := SYSDATE+P_DAYS;
RETURN V_DATE;
END;
```

When I select this:

```
select GET_DATE(3)
from dual;
```

I got following:

`2015-03-13`

How can i get the `HH24:MI` added to it like this?

`2015-03-13 21:34`

Comment: What IDE are you using? Sql developer or Toad maybe? This is an IDE issue not oracle. `DATE` by definition has time inside it. The reason you don't see it in the select statement is due to the NLS settings of your IDE. Or look at @aramillo's edited answer.

Comment: @ruudvan i am using sql developer

Comment: I agree with @JustinCave. However to complete my train of thought - Just do this in sql developer - Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> NLS -> Date Format -> (change this to include the time). The Default date format in sql developer doesn't have time. Please note that this is only for display. This doesn't mean that the function wasn't returning the times.

Comment: @ruudvan so i cant get the hour and minutes thrue som TO_CHAR or something else? i have been stucked with this for a couple of days now

Comment: Do what Aramillo's answer says. If you have trouble displaying the date values like doing `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL` which has time but displays only as a date without a time; that is when you need to fix the format settings of the IDE.

Comment: @ruudvan ok, but when someone else is running my code they gonna have maybe the same problem? not showing hours and minutes?

Comment: And that is exactly why you convert it to a string when displaying it, so as to not be affected by the database nls_date_format parameter or any local IDE settings.

Comment: @ruudvan but the problem is the assignment says that you are suppose to run: 

SELECT GET_DATE(3) FROM DUAL; 

And not SELECT to_char(GET_DATE(3), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') from dual

That's why i am stuck..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select to_char(GET_DATE(3),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') from dual
```

Also can change nls_date_format:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi';
select GET_DATE(3) from dual;
```

Other solution, change the function to return a varchar2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DATE(P_DAYS IN  NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
RETURN to_char(SYSDATE+P_DAYS,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi');
END;

select GET_DATE(3) from dual;
```

Output:

```
Function created.

GET_DATE(3)                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-03-13 16:32                                                                
1 row selected.
```

Comment: Well the assignment is only to use SELECT GET_DATE(3) from dual;

So thats why i am stuck with this : (

Comment: How shall i write it then?

Comment: Well i tried @NoDisplayName solution.. but DATETIME doesn't work? :I

Comment: @Aramillo the assignment is to use SELECT GET_DATE(3) FROM DUAL;.. 

I cannot use select to char and so on.. : (

Comment: You can also use nls_date_format. Please check

Comment: ? is it not possible to get hour and seconds from my code? i mean isnt it suppose to work with TO_CHAR or something? do i really need to change my nls_date_format? 

sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Problem is you are returning a date. The way of date is displayed depends of nls_date_settings, this means that you can see the date in a format and someone else in other server in other format. You can return in your function a varchar instead and problem solved

Comment: Can you show me an example @Aramillo? with the varchar thing?

Comment: thank you for the example.. When i run it i got this:

01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

is that because of my nls_date_format is in YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: No, nls_settings doesn't matter because you are working with varchar now, did you call the function without to_char? Please check the answer i post the example i'm running in my db.

Comment: i did excactly as you did.. copy the code but still the error message "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Comment: i got it worked now.. with this

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DATE(p_days IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    v_date VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    v_date := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + p_days, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
    RETURN v_date;
END;
/

Comment: Ah, ok. Glad to ear that, but still i don't see where was the problem before :)

Comment: i dont know either.. it was really strange.. Thank you for your time for helping me.. i really glad that you gave me example and so on.. thank you